# How to calculate the face normal derivation of vertex coordinates?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry

## Briefed

How to calculate face normal $FN$ of vertex coordiates $v_0$?

## Detail

Triangle mesh is composed of Vertex set $V$ and Face set $F$.

Consider a face $(v_0, v_1, v_2)$, we can easily get its face normal $FN$ by

$$
FN=\vec{a}\times\vec{b}\\
\vec{a}=v_2-v_1\\
\vec{b}=v_0-v_1
$$

in which $v_0, v_1, v_2$ are 3D coordiates of vertices.

How to calculate
$\frac{\partial FN}{\partial v_0}, \frac{\partial FN}{\partial v_1},\frac{\partial FN}{\partial v_2}$

Comment: Your orientation seems the opposite of what I would want. I would use $\vec a = v_1-v_0$ and $\vec b=v_2-v_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if we change $v_0$ by $\Delta v_0$, then $\Delta FN = \vec a\times \Delta\vec b = \vec a\times \Delta v_0$. If we change $v_1$ by $\Delta v_1$, then $\Delta FN = \Delta\vec a\times\vec b + \vec a\times\Delta\vec b = -(\Delta v_1\times\vec b + \vec a\times\Delta v_1)=(\vec b-\vec a)\times\Delta v_1=(v_0-v_2)\times\Delta v_1$, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of bad at math. What is the meaning of $\Delta{v_0}$?

Comment: $\Delta$ means *change in*, just as in beginning calculus. Writing the derivative with respect to a vector can be tricky, so I chose the most direct approach possible.

Comment: Is $\frac{\partial{\vec{v_0}}}{\partial{\vec{v_0}}}$ an Identity matrix?

Comment: Yes, as you’re differentiating the identity map. But you won’t have nice matrices for your problem, and you will get bogged down with horrid coordinates. In multivariable problems, often for best understanding one should give directional derivatives in arbitrary directions — as I did without being fancy — rather than a horrid huge matrix.